# Передача массива в другую функцию

Tags: c#

Как можно реализовать передачу массива из одной функции в другую? Перепробовал уже несколько способов, но к сожалению они не хотят работать. Мне нужно, чтобы элементы массива из функции Add() передались в функцию Dump() и там вывести список этих элементов. Или такое реализуется с помощью List?

```
using System;

namespace organizer

{

internal class Program

{

    public static int Day { get; set; }

    public static int Quantity { get; set; }

    public static int Month { get; set; }

    private static void Add(string[] months)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер месяца в который вы хотите добавить дело");

        int counter = 1;
        foreach (string mont in months)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(months[counter++] + $" - {counter - 1}");
            if (counter > 12)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25));

        Console.Write("Номер месяца: ");
        Month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Введите день месяца на который вы хотите добавить дело: ");
        Day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (Month == 2)
        {
            while (Day > 28)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("В феврале 28 дней.");
                Console.Write("Введите значение повторно: ");
                Day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Day < 28 || Day <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25));

        Console.Write("Введите количество дел которые вы хотите добавить: ");
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.WriteLine($"Какие дела вы хотите добавить в {months[Month]} на день {Day}?");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25));
        Console.WriteLine($"Количество дел которое надо добавить: {Quantity}");

        string[] affairs = new string[Quantity];



        for (int i = 0; i < affairs.Length; i++)
        {
            affairs[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Осталось добавить дел: {--Quantity}");
        }



    }

    private static void Dump(string month, int day)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Список дел на {month[Month]} в день {day}");

        //foreach (var aff in affairs)
        //{
        //    Console.Write(aff);
        //}
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string[] months = new string[13];

        #region Months
        months[0] = "Months:";
        months[1] = "January";
        months[2] = "February";
        months[3] = "March";
        months[4] = "April";
        months[5] = "May";
        months[6] = "June";
        months[7] = "July";
        months[8] = "August";
        months[9] = "September";
        months[10] = "October";
        months[11] = "November";
        months[12] = "December";
        #endregion

        Console.WriteLine("LKL");
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите номер операции которую хотите выполнить:" +
            "\n1 - Добавить список дел" +
            "\n2 - Вывести список дел" +
            "\n3 - Перенести дела на следующий месяц");

        int choice;

        while (true)
        {
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Add(months);
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                Dump(months[Month], Day);
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так у вас все статичное так что обрашатся ко всем элементам класса через 
 **.** Пример :Program.

```
           private static void Dump()
            {
                foreach (var month in Program.Add)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Список дел на {month[month]} в день {Program.Day}");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Только вот у вас код не совсем правильный день всегда будет отображаться один и тот же а точнее последний введенный день

Comment: я бы вам рекомендовал сделать класс "Tasks" ссполями int Day , string Month, string TaskInfo  и заполнять список с этим классом а потом его выводить если надо

Comment: Зачем Вы пишете комментарии к своему-же ответу? Добавьте это непосредственно в ответ.

Comment: функционал ещё просто Dump() не полностью сделал, так что пока так

Answer (score 0):

Заведите словарь внутри класса, в котором будете все хранить, и в Dump его передавайте. Только static уберите.

Comment: а можно по подробнее как это реализовать? Просто не до конца понимаю, потому что значения задаются пользователем в методе Add и надо как-то их вытащить в метод Dump

Comment: у вас, во-первых в функцию Dump передается только месяц и день, однако нет базы, где хранятся добавленные дела.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eAZbQLrP вот класс, который может подойти для вашей задачи. Просмотрите его внимательно и попробуйте разобраться